# Use a simplified HTML version for search bots

Tags: technical-seo, prerender

As my site is an Angular single page application, for search bots, I serve a static preloaded version of HTML for search bots using [prerender](https://github.com/prerender/prerender).

SEO tools are complaining that the HTML to text ratio is too high (0.99) and I am wondering if it is fine to serve a simplified version of HTML to search bots, where irrelevant elements are removed from the HTML and only the actual content is displayed. The site has no other issues, it loads fast.

Would this be considered a violation and would cause a de-ranking of the site?

Definitely, decreasing HTML size and maintaining that would impede development speed.

Comment: You may fall afoul of "cloaking" rules.

Comment: Are you able to push some of the HTML into CSS into another file?